# An infinite loop caused because of two getters?

Tags: javascript, properties, accessor

The following code executes an infinite loop (prints `getter1` once, and then `getter2` until stopped):

```
var person1 = {
    _age: 42,
    get age() {
      console.log("getter1");
      return this._age;
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(person1, "_age", {
    get: function() {
      console.log("getter2");
      return this._age;
  }
});
console.log(person1.age); // true
```

What causes it? (Note: I'm aware to the fact that I declared two different getters).

Comment: The second getter gets itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, but infinite recursion. You're return `this._age` inside a getter for `_age`, but accessing `this._age` implicitly calls the getter again.

Note that once you've defined a getter called `_age` the old value of `_age` (42) is overwritten. There is no property with the value `42` anymore. If you want to create a getter that returns the value of a property it can't be the getter for that same property, so name your getter something other than `_age`:

```
var person1 = {
    _age: 42,
    get age() {
      console.log("getter1");
      return this._age;
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(person1, "age2", {
    get: function() {
      console.log("getter2");
      return this._age;
  }
});
console.log(person1.age); // 42
console.log(person1.age2); // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you return a value from a getter you fire the other getter

Answer (score 0):

Your first getter is asking for `this._get` this triggers the second getter, which asks for `this._get` which triggers the second getter, which asks for `this._get`, which triggers... you get the point.